# When click on link execute onclick="function()" to increment a value on my database

Tags: php, html, sql

Im making a forum and in one of the pages i show the topics i have with an id i got from the page before, and in that page i also want to show how many visits the topics have, as such i call the id of the topic, put it in a function that i call to when i click on a link with onclick, so that once somebody clicks on it to access it, it also updates the visits count on the database.  Point is, it doesnt work.

PHP CALL

```
<?php
    include("db.php");
    $sql="SELECT `id`, `nombre`, `creador`, `dept_no`, `fechac`, `visitas` FROM `temas` WHERE `dept_no`=".(desencryptar($_GET["id"]));
    if($resultado = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
       if($resultado->num_rows>0){
          while($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
             $id=$fila["id"];
             $nombre=$fila["nombre"];
             $creador=$fila["creador"];
             $dept_no=$fila["dept_no"];
             $fechac=$fila["fechac"];
             $visitas=$fila["visitas"];  ?>
```

After which i call it when showing it.

HTML

```
<tr>
   <td>
      <a onclick="visitas(<?php echo $id;?>)" id="tema" href="posts.php?id=<?php echo encryptar($id);?>" target="_self"><?php echo $nombre;?></a>
      <div style="padding-top:5px">
           <span>Por<a href="perfil.php?id=<?php echo $creador;?>"> <?php echo $creador;?></a>, <?php echo $fechac;?></span>
       </div>
   </td>
   <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo Contar($id);?></td>
   <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $visitas;?></td>
   <td>Por<a href="perfil.php"> <?php echo $creador;?></a><br><span>En </span><?php echo $fechac;?></td>
```

PHP FUNCTION i created on a functions.php

```
function visitas($valor) {
include("db.php");
$sql2="UPDATE `temas` SET `visitas` = `visitas` + 1 WHERE `id`=".$valor; }
```

Answer (score 1):

you are using a Javascript Function visitas() and created a PHP function visitas ?

Know that Javascript function can't execute PHP function...

You need to create a Javascript function that will execute a Ajax request to a php file that contain your Php function, then redirect the user after success response.

**Example:**

[jQuery Ajax POST example with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php)

Comment: Hi zrry, it is a php functions, like all the other ones, though can you specify what you see as the javascript function? and in terms of what to do for it to fit the php

Comment: What is the function for onclick="visitas(<?php echo $id;?>)" ? because i only see a PHP function in your post.